# c# Access OleDB err 80004005

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

I'm working on an app with an Access 2010 db connection and I keep receiving OleDB error 80004005 and I can't figure out why.

```
            const String conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\OneDrive\Dropbox\SharpDevelop Projects\electronics inventory\electronics.mdb";
    const String qCont = "select Section, Number, Stock from Container where Component = @IdComp order by Section, Number";

    int oldParamSubcat = 0;
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);

    void GrdCompCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        String IdComp = grdComp[grdComp.Columns["ID"].Index, grdComp.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        try
        {
            grdSubcat.DataSource = null;
            grdSubcat.Rows.Clear();
            grdSubcat.Columns.Clear();
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmdDetail = new OleDbCommand();
            cmdDetail.Connection = connection;
            cmdDetail.CommandText = qDetail;
            cmdDetail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdComp", Convert.ToInt32(IdComp));

            txtDetails.Text = "";
            OleDbDataReader rdDetail = cmdDetail.ExecuteReader();

            rdDetail.Read();
            txtDetails.Text = rdDetail["Component"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            txtDetails.Text += rdDetail["Parameter"].ToString() + ": ";
            txtDetails.Text += rdDetail["Val"].ToString() + "\r\n";

            while(rdDetail.Read())
            {
                txtDetails.Text += rdDetail["Parameter"].ToString() + ": ";
                txtDetails.Text += rdDetail["Val"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            }

            rdDetail.Close();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmdCode = new OleDbCommand();
            cmdCode.Connection = connection;
            cmdCode.CommandText = qCode;
            cmdCode.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdComp", Convert.ToInt32(IdComp));

            txtDetails.Text += "\r\n";
            OleDbDataReader rdCode = cmdCode.ExecuteReader();

            while(rdCode.Read())
            {
                txtDetails.Text += rdCode["Seller"].ToString() + ": ";
                txtDetails.Text += rdCode["Code"].ToString() + "\r\n";
            }

            rdCode.Close();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmdCont = new OleDbCommand();
            cmdCont.Connection = connection;
            cmdCont.CommandText = qCont;
            cmdCont.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdComp", Convert.ToInt32(IdComp));

            txtDetails.Text += "\r\n";
            OleDbDataReader rdCont = cmdCont.ExecuteReader(); ////////// here is where i receive the error ///////////////

            while(rdCont.Read())
            {
                txtDetails.Text += "Container: ";
                txtDetails.Text += rdCont["Section"].ToString() + "-";
                txtDetails.Text += rdCont["Number"].ToString() + " = ";
                txtDetails.Text += rdCont["Stock"].ToString() + " units\r\n";
            }

            rdCont.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code works perfectly, I only get the error on cmdCont.ExecuteReader();
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hv3d.png)
If i execute the query in Access, it runs ok.
Any ideas are very much welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you closing and reopening your connection?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no relationships between these informations? Perhaps you don't need to use three different queries to get the data from your db.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm closing and reopening because, in some cases, opening a 3rd reader on the same connection result in an error (don't know why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words *Section*, *Number* and *Container* are listed between the [reserved keyword for MS-Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2?ocmsassetID=HA010030643&CorrelationId=feebde96-a814-40d1-923f-c92244239faa&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#duplicate=0). You shouldn't use them in your table schema but if you really can't change these names to something different then you need to put them between square brackets

```
const String qCont = @"select [Section], [Number], Stock from [Container]
                       where Component = @IdComp order by [Section], [Number]";
```

Also you should use a more robust approach to your disposable objects like the connection, the commands and the readers. Try to add the using statement to your code in this way:

```
try
{
    ....
    using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(......))
    {
         connection.Open();
         ....
         string cmdText = "yourdetailquery";
         using(OleDbCommand cmdDetail = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
         {
             .... // parameters
             using(OleDbDataReader rdDetail = cmdDetail.ExecuteReader())
             {
               ... read detail data .... 
             }
         }
         // here the rdDetail is closed and disposed, 
         // you can start a new reader without closing the connection
         cmdText = "yourcodequery";
         using(OleDbCommand cmdCode = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection))
         {
             .... parameters
             using(OleDbReader rdCode = cmdCode.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 // read code data...
             }
         }
         ... other command+reader
   }
   // Here the connection is closed and disposed
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // any error goes here with the connection closed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about "section" and "number" (and changed them accordingly). But I didn't realize that "container" was also reserved.

Comment: Me too. MS-Access has these quirks that sometime are really annoying